# How to do real time inventory sync with Square and Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, square

I am using SquarePos, is possible real time inventory sync with Square and Magento

Answer (score 1):

It is possible if Magento has integrated Square's V2 Webhooks which help you to subscribe to any inventory changes - 
https://developer.squareup.com/docs/webhooks-api/what-it-does.